# Git cannot create shallow-since locally

Tags: git, git-clone, repo, shallow-copy

I am trying to create a --shallow-since working clone from a local bare clone but it keeps pulling everything. --depth=N works fine.

I'm thinking the issue is I'm using the wrong format? I've tried searching but no where does it explicitly say what format < date > is supposed to be for --shallow-since=< date >.

Comment: Hmm, what you say makes sense... It seems to wok consistently when I get a shallow repo using depth=1 so thanks for that.

That being said I'm experience some weird behavior where if I fetch the initial fetch (after git init and adding the remote) with shallow-since it will work for some dates but not for closer dates beyond a point. I just assumed my formatting was wrong but I guess I need a shallow working dir first...

Comment: @torek `git clone --shallow-since=YYYY-MM-DD` worked just fine to clone a new local repo for me.. why do you say it 'deepens or shortens the shallowness of an existing clone. It does not make a new clone be a shallow clone'?

Comment: @user2561747: the OP was trying to take an existing non-shallow clone and turn it into a shallow clone, if I remember right. But yes, the text in the comment above is pretty misleading now (I guess some context has gone away). I think I will just delete that comment...

Answer (score 16):

Format is YYYY-MM-DD

See above comment for what confused me and how that confusion was resolved.

Comment: Just for the record: You can also do thinks like 1week 3month or 2years

Answer (score 4):

I used:

`--shallow-since="3 years"`

and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Using UNIX timestamp:

```sh
git fetch upstream master --shallow-since=1589324214
```

on `git version 2.26.2.windows.1` and in GitHub actions CI also works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

While the date format is indeed, for instance, YYYY-MM-DD,  "`git fetch --shallow-since=<cutoff>`" had a problem:

If you specify a cut-off point that is *newer* than the existing history, it  used to end up grabbing the entire history.
Such a request now errors out with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018).

See [commit e34de73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e34de73c5653c713e6edddc5a12c8befc50d311f) (26 May 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 208ee59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/208ee598612092da892ac1c0e8dd0d4e09c4f076), 25 Jun 2018)</sup>

> ### `upload-pack`: reject shallow requests that would return nothing
>
> Shallow clones with `--shallow-since` or `--shalow-exclude` work by running rev-list to get all reachable commits, then draw a boundary between reachable and unreachable and send "shallow" requests based on that.
>
> The code does miss one corner case: if `rev-list` returns nothing, we'll have no border and we'll send no shallow requests back to the client (i.e. no history cuts).
>   This essentially means a full clone (or a full branch if the client requests just one branch).
>   One example is the oldest commit is older than what is specified by --shallow-since.
>
> To avoid this, if `rev-list` returns nothing, we abort the clone/fetch.
>   The user could adjust their request (e.g. `--shallow-since` further back in the past) and retry.
>
> Another possible option for this case is to fall back to a default
>   depth (like depth 1).
>   But I don't like too much magic that way because we may return something unexpected to the user. If they request "history since 2008" and we return a single depth at 2000, that might break stuff for them.
>   It is better to tell them that something is wrong and let them take the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

```
--shallow-since=<date>
    Deepen or shorten the history of a shallow repository to include all reachable commits after <date>.
```

The format of the date is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`, eg: `2020-04-13T11:01:01`