# new_git_repository shallow_since field format

Tags: bazel, git-clone

I've a `new_git_repository` containing:

```py
new_git_repository(
    name = "hyperscan",
    build_file = "//external-deps/hyperscan:BUILD",
    commit = "[COMMIT_HASH]",
    remote = "https://github.com/intel/hyperscan.git",
    shallow_since = "2018-07-09",
)
```

When building it says:

```
DEBUG: Rule 'hyperscan' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1531154744 -0400"
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43880133/1655335), shouldn't the `shallow_since` format be of `YYYY-MM-DD`?
And next, what does `shallow_since = "1531154744 -0400"` mean?!

Comment: Any Idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bazel does not process the string specified as `shallow_since` attribute and passes it directly to git as `--shallow-since` parameter. It can be seen in Bazel source code [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_defs/repo/git_worker.bzl#L60).

The value you see is Git internal date format which is `<unix timestamp> <time zone offset>`, where `<unix timestamp>` is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch. `<time zone offset>` is a positive or negative offset from UTC. For example CET (which is 1 hour ahead of UTC) is `+0100`.

[Here](https://www.epochconverter.com/) is the tool for `unix timestamp` conversion to the human-readable date/time and back.

Bazel uses git log --date=raw to get the timestamp of the commit, and then does a string comparison with the value of shallow_since. In my opinion, it is a bug in Bazel - it should do a date comparison instead.

Comment: OK. But, git clone accepts both formats (`unix timestamp` and `YYYY-MM-DD`) as a `shallow_since` argument. The problem is: when I set a shallow_since in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` bazel warns me to set the shallow_since! (Seems it discards the date or something similar)

Comment: Bazel uses `git log --date=raw` to get the timestamp of the commit, and then does a string comparison with the value of shallow_since. In my opinion, it is a bug in Bazel - it should do a date comparison instead.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you add this important point to the answer so I can accept it as a correct.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the comments, you can use `git log --date=raw` to get the `commit` sha and the time (`shallow_since`) of the desired commit.